# Continue Code after pressing Button

Tags: c#, winforms, events, button, ini

Information given in a `Textbox` and the Code should stop and wait for the User to press the `Button`, so  he "show" he had read the Information...

After this the code should run forward and wait again at the next loop

(I looked for Events and so on but i don't find any solution)

```
  public void Auslesen(object e, EventArgs myevent)
    {

        StringBuilder strbuildsection = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder strbuildbetreff = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder strbuildinhalt = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder strbuilduser = new StringBuilder(System.Environment.UserName);
        StringBuilder strbuildusercheck = new StringBuilder();


        foreach (string Ccat in this.ini.IniGetCategories())
        {
            string readval = ini.IniReadValue(Ccat, "Read");
            string usercheckvar = (this.ini.IniReadValue(Ccat, "SpecifyUser"));
            string user = System.Environment.UserName;

            if (readval == "0")
            {
                if (usercheckvar == user || usercheckvar.Equals("All"))
                {
                    strbuildsection.Append(Ccat + Environment.NewLine);

                    foreach (string cat in this.ini.IniGetKeys(Ccat))
                    {
                        strbuildinhalt.Clear();
                        strbuildusercheck.Clear();
                        strbuildbetreff.Clear();

                        strbuildbetreff.Append(this.ini.IniReadValue(Ccat, "Betreff") + Environment.NewLine);
                        strbuildinhalt.Append(this.ini.IniReadValue(Ccat, "Inhalt") + Environment.NewLine);
                    }

                    textBox1.AppendText(strbuildsection.ToString() + strbuildbetreff.ToString() + strbuildinhalt.ToString() + strbuildusercheck.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
                        strbuildsection.Clear();

                    //
                    //
                    //
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: In any event, it's some sort of event-driven program. Such programs do not "stop" for the user. Instead, they _react_ to the user.

Comment: And how they 'react' with user?

Comment: Events are fired when the user does something. All of the code of the application is in event handlers, reacting to the events.

Comment: But this should run totally in the background, popup when a new "message" found in my INI and displayed to the user and the user should "accept" it with pressing the `button` @JohnSaunders

Answer (score 0):

If you want your program to stop to allow the user to acknowledge an event use the message box.

```
MessageBox.Show("Your message here.");
```

The user will have to click the OK button before the program will continue.

Here is the MSDN documentation on MessageBox.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505(v=vs.85).aspx